# Необходимость блокировки при считывании/записи переменной

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Нужна ли блокировка `lock` в C# при считывании / записи переменной?

Пример кода:

```
Int i = 0;

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 500;
timer.backFunc += readVar;

Thread th = new Thread();
th.backFunc += setVar;

th.Run();
timer.Run();    

void readVar()
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

void setVar()
{
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Обновление:**

Смотрите. Есть простое правило: если доступ к переменной происходит из нескольких потоков (всё равно, чтение или запись), то это чтение нужно окружать `lock`'ом. Несоблюдение этого правила может привести к немедленно видимому неправильному результату, но (что гораздо хуже!) может и появлению неправильного результата очень редко! Таким образом, у вас могут появиться трудновоспроизводимые вылеты программы.

Это правило действует даже для случая, когда переменная «маленькая» (например, `int`), и может быть записана «в один присест». О точных причинах смотрите этот ответ ниже и другие ответы, а также дискуссию в комментариях.

В вашем случае колбеки от таймера (модифицирующие) приходят не том же потоке, что считывающий код, поэтому есть необходимость в блокировке.

Это правило не абсолютное: существуют случаи, когда на самом деле *можно* избежать блокировок. Но для этого необходимо знать тонкости о работе современных процессоров, оптимизаторов и конкретного оборудования, и очень легко допустить ошибку. Поэтому мой совет — не старайтесь любой ценой избегать блокировок, игра часто не стоит свеч. Хуже того, тестирование часто *не* покажет вам проблемы с кодом.

---

Важный случай, когда блокировки *не* нужны — использование TPL и `async`/`await` для конкурентного доступа без выгрузки работы в дополнительный поток.

Пример:

```
int x = 0;

async Task RunVariableChange(int howManyTimes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howManyTimes; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        x++;
    }
}

async Task ReadVariable(CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(750, ct);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // ничего не делать, это ожидаемое исключение
    }
}

// использование (*)
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var readTask = ReadVariable(cts.Token);
await RunVariableChange(20);
cts.Cancel();
await readTask;
```

Если код `(*)` бежит в UI-потоке, то все случаи доступа к переменной происходят в нём, и нужды в блокировке нет. По сути у нас тут нет *многопоточного* кода! (Однако, блокировки всё ещё нужны, если `Task` запускается не в UI-потоке, например, через `Task.Run`.)

Кроме того, использование *локальной* переменной в `async`-методе безопасно даже если этот метод «перепрыгивает» из потока в поток, поскольку каждый `await` является точкой синхронизации.

(Поэтому старайтесь использовать «функциональный» подход: работайте не с разделяемыми, а с локальными переменными, получайте данные на вход как параметры, и возвращайте результат как return-значение функции: это уменьшит потребность в блокировках.)

---

**Старый ответ:**

Да.

Если код модифицирует переменную, то многопоточный доступ требует защиты memory barrier'ом, например, `lock`'ом.

Иначе как оптимизатор, так и кэш процессора вправе считать, что переменная не меняется.

---

Пример с кэшем процессора: допустим, поток #1 выполняется на процессоре #1, а поток #2 — на процессоре #2. Поток #1 записывает новое значение переменной. Это значение попадает в кэш процессора #1, но не «проваливается» сразу в память, т. к. синхронизация с памятью — процесс *очень* медленный. Теперь, поток #2 читает значение, из кэша процессора #2, а там оно старое!

Принудительный «сброс» кэша процессора в память — один из эффектов, которые вызывает `lock`.

---

Почему же при этом такой эффект редко виден на деле? Дело в том, что сброс кэша иногда может происходить по внешним причинам, например, при переключении контекста.

---

Я надеюсь, я правильно понял назначение вашего кода. Мне пришлось угадывать, поскольку ни `Thread`, ни `Timer` не содержат event'а `backFunc`.

Comment: В случае же с исходным примером (один писатель, один читатель) достаточно будет пометить поле `volatile`.

Comment: @andreycha: Хм. Покажете место в документации, где об этом говорится?

Comment: @andreycha: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword Чтение может выдать устаревшее значение

Comment: О как, не знал. Получается, его вообще бессмысленно использовать.

Comment: @andreycha: Вот ещё от Эрика: http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/ (и вот ещё: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx)

Comment: @VladD lock не даёт войти разным потокам в один участок кода. В данном случае и поток таймера, и отдельный поток используют разные участки кода. Имхо, lock не нужен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Нет, `lock` делает гораздо больше. Например, memory barrier. Вы всё же почитайте упомянутые в комментариях статьи.

Comment: @VladD, будет ли разница в синхронизации если в данном примере использовать Task вместо Thread?

Comment: @z668: Да! Я обновлю ответ, спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: @z668: Дописал ответ.

Comment: @VladD, судя по тому что я видел тут и на других ресурсах в ответах, большинство девелоперов не знает об этом аспекте (крайне важном кстати). Почти все используют простые типы полей без какой либо синхронизации в множестве потоков. Я думаю этот нюанс достоин выноса в отдельную статью дабы подобные ошибки не повторялись большинством.

Comment: @z668: Платформа x86 прощает многие ошибки, поэтому многие ошибки проходят незамеченными. Написать отдельно имеет смысл, да.

Answer (score 3):

Почему-то предыдущие ответы сразу ушли в дебри моделей памяти, которые все равно толком никто не понимает. ИМХО, есть гораздо более простая причина, почему в случае инкремента переменной нужна синхронизация.

По факту, `i++` не является атомарной операцией, а является тройкой - read-modify-write. Перепишите метод `setVal` следующим образом:

```
void SetVal()
{
  var tempI = i;
  // пустота!
  i = tempI + 1;
}
```

Теперь должно быть понятным, что при наличии более одного потока (а наличие таймера говорит о наличии более одного потока), ОС-ка может переключить контекст исполнения в строке с комментом `пустота`. В результате, будет следующее:

```
Начальный момент времени
i == 42!
Thread 1:
Прочитал i, записал в tempI 42
Контекст переключился на другой поток

Thread 2:
Прочитал i, записал в tempI 42
Записал в i tempI + 1, т.е. i теперь равна 43.
Контекст переключился на первый поток

Thread 1:
(tempI у этого потока хранит все то же старое значение, 42)
Записал в i tempI + 1, т.е. i равна 43!
```

Вот так мы потеряли один инкремент.

Теперь наша задача сделать инкремент, т.е. операцию read-modify-write - атомарной (т.е. неделимой с точки зрения процесса исполнения). Также нам нужно сделать и так, чтобы потоки каждый раз вычитывали наиболее актуальные значения, но, в простых случаях (без всякой lock-free магии, о которой, судя по вопросу, пока не время заморачиваться) эти две проблемы будут решены одним махом.

Большинство современных сред исполнения содержат библиотеки для атомарного увелчения целых чисел. Так, в .NET Framework есть класс `Interlocked`, который содержит ряд методов, в частности, предложенный `Increment(ref int)`.

Альтернативой является обернуть доступ к разделяемой переменной некоторым примитивом синхронизации, например, конструкцией `lock`.

Вот пример, который показывает, почему синхронизация важна:

```
private static int _lockLessCount;
private static int _lockFreeCount;

private static int _lockBasedCount;
private static object _countLock = new object();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numberOfIterations = 1000000;
    var t1 = Task.Run(() => { for (int n = 0; n < numberOfIterations; n++) _lockLessCount++; });
    var t2 = Task.Run(() => { for (int n = 0; n < numberOfIterations; n++) _lockLessCount++; });
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

    var t3 = Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < numberOfIterations; n++) 
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _lockFreeCount);
        });
    var t4 = Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < numberOfIterations; n++) 
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _lockFreeCount);
        });
    Task.WaitAll(t3, t4);

    var t5 = Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < numberOfIterations; n++) 
                lock (_countLock) { _lockBasedCount++; }
        });
    var t6 = Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < numberOfIterations; n++)
                lock (_countLock) { _lockBasedCount++; }
        });
    Task.WaitAll(t5, t6);

    Console.WriteLine("Iterations: {0}", numberOfIterations);
    Console.WriteLine("LockLessCount: {0}", _lockLessCount);
    Console.WriteLine("LockFreeCount: {0}", _lockFreeCount);
    Console.WriteLine("LockBasedCount: {0}", _lockBasedCount);

    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```

Если бы синхронизация была не нужна, то при запуске мы бы увидели одинаковые значения, но это не так.

Вот результат вывода на моем локальном компьюетере:

```
Iterations: 1000000
LockLessCount: 1611802
LockFreeCount: 2000000
LockBasedCount: 2000000
Done!
```

Как видно, при "простом" доступе, мы потеряли почти 400 тысяч значений!

Comment: `Interlocked.Increment` гарантирует только атомарность. Он не пропагирует изменения в другой поток. Вот статья Эрика о том, почему нужна синхронизация и при чтении: http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/

Comment: Да, я с этим не спорю:) У меня ж вообще аспект чтения пропущен. 
Мой поинт в том, что судя по уровню вопроса, нет смысла давать в ответах модели памяти, нужно дать топикстартеру понимание проблемы.

Comment: Поинт тейкен! Допишу-ка я ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, в Вашем коде совершенно не требуется `lock`. Хотя одну операцию всё же придётся изменить - метод `setVar` должен выглядеть так:

```
void setVar()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
}
```

С этим Ваш код защищён от гонок.

---

Единственным недостатком такого подхода является следующее:
допустим `setVar` исполняется в потоке 1(П1), тогда как `readVar` в потоке 2(П2). Допустим, что `setVar` был вызван уже 5 раз и менял значения `i` на следующее `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Теперь `readVar` получает свой квант времени и может прочитать *любое* значение из вышеперечисленных. Единственное ограничение состоит в том, что `readVar` не может прочитать значение, которые было раньше, чем уже прочитанное в этом потоке. К примеру, в первый вызов `readVar` прочитал `3`, это значит, что в следующем вызове `readVar` может быть прочитано `[3,4,5]` и никакого другого значения.

Но это всё в теории, на процессорах `x86` и `amd64`, `readVar` всегда прочитает последнее значение. На `ARM` не всегда. Больше .NET нет нигде, насколько я знаю.

`lock` сериализует доступ к переменной, поэтому он гарантирует, что при чтении всегда будет получено последнее записанное под `lock` значение(если конечно все операции записи находятся под `lock`'ом). Это, разумеется, не бесплатно и в общем случае код использующий `lock` *может* быть медленее. Но понятнее.

Comment: [Неверно](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6139812/276994). Если вы хотите спуститься на нижний уровень, нужен ещё как минимум [`VolatileRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatileread.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, что не верно? Вышеописанный код полностью корректен. Да, гарантии чтения последнего значения нет, а это требовалось?

Comment: `Interlocked.Increment`, согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx), делает увеличение _атомарным_. Оно не приводит автоматически к когерентности кэшей.

Comment: @VladD, а причём тут когерентность? Что мы синхронизируем? У нас есть одна переменная, которую нужно инкрементировать и прочитать, имея T1 и T2, где в T1 происходит инкремент, а в T2 чтения(T2 позже T1). Мы не имеем гарантии, что в T2 будет прочитан результат T1(на самом деле на x86 имеем, так что такая ситуация может быть только на ARM, из поддерживаемых .NET). Но рано или поздно результат T1 всё таки поступит в `readVar()`(и это будет довольно быстро)

Comment: ... а если недостаточно быстро, то надо вставить `Sleep(100)`?

Comment: @VladD, ничего там вставлять не надо. Я не понимаю, что не так? Код выше это вполне корректный lock-free code. Lock там совершенно не нужен, пока дополнительных требований не выставил автор.

Comment: Мы синхронизируем вид на переменную `i` из запущнного нами потока и потока, на котором доставляются события от таймера, разумеется.

Comment: Ах, вы в этом смысле! Ну если требования получить правильный результат нет, то любой код подойдёт.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25237/discussion-between-ixsci-and-vladd).

Comment: Кстати: большая часть, если не весь "lock-free code", который приходил в вопросах на этот сайт (включая Хэшкод), содержала зияющие гонки.

Answer (score 0):

в последнем примере от Sergey Teplyakov еще попробовал volatule и получил:

```
Iterations: 1000000
LockLessCount: 1483306
LockFreeCount: 2000000
LockBasedCount: 2000000
LockVolatileCount: 65866
Done!
```

И еще попробовал Брэкпойнт на `Console.WriteLine("Done!")` и увидел:

```
LockLessCount: 2000000 LockVolatileCount: 137415
```

IMHO:

1. Дебаггером такие ошибки не обнаркжить.
2. Volatile похоже помогает только для чтения в другом потоке